# Ubuntu desktop 22.04 LTS - ethernet connection not working

Tags: ethernet, ubuntu-22.04

I have been installed ubuntu desktop 22.04 LTS with ethernet connetion on my **Dell Inc. Latitude E7240** computer, it worked properly,
but today in time of work, the ethernet connection is not working

In windows 10 it works properly, wirless connection it works too!

Only cable network connection is not working in my ubuntu 22.04

Anyone can help? Please!.

```
 rfkill list all
```

showed

```
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: nfc0: NFC
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

.

```
sudo lshw -sanitize -c network
```

showed

```
*-network DESABILITADO    
       descrição: Ethernet interface
       produto: Ethernet Connection I218-LM
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       ID físico: 19
       informações do barramento: pci@0000:00:19.0
       nome lógico: eno1
       versão: 04
       serial: [REMOVED]
       capacidade: 1Gbit/s
       largura: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuração: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.15.0-33-generic firmware=0.7-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       recursos: irq:46 memória:f7e00000-f7e1ffff memória:f7e3c000-f7e3cfff porta de E/S:f080(tamanho=32)
  *-network
       descrição: Interface sem fio
       produto: Wireless 7260
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       ID físico: 0
       informações do barramento: pci@0000:02:00.0
       nome lógico: wlp2s0
       versão: 73
       serial: [REMOVED]
       largura: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuração: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-33-generic firmware=17.3216344376.0 7260-17.ucode ip=[REMOVED] latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       recursos: irq:50 memória:f7d00000-f7d01fff
```

Answer (score 0):

I runned bellow:

```
 sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Comment: Unfortunately your question/answer(?) is totally 'off topic' here because you asked it in the wrong part of the metaverse. It would be much better placed at https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: thanks for show me how I can do if future in this case